# What is the minimum $n$ for which $\Bbb H^3$ can be isometrically embedded in $\Bbb R^n$ as a bounded set?

Tags: riemannian-geometry, hyperbolic-geometry, embeddings, isometries

Consider the hyperbolic $3$-space $\Bbb H^3$ (i.e., the unique, simply-connected, $3$-dimensional complete Riemannian manifold with a constant negative sectional curvature equal to $-1$). The Nash embedding theorem says that $\Bbb H^3$ can be isometrically (i.e., preserving the length of every path) embedded into some $\Bbb R^n$.

> What is the minimum $n$ for which $\Bbb H^3$ can be isometrically
> embedded in $\Bbb R^n$ such that the image of the embedding is
> bounded?

Comment: H^3 has an isometric embedding into a compact 6-manifold, which in turn has a (continuously differentiable) isometric embedding into R^12 by the Nash-Kuiper theorem. So 12 suffices in the C^1 category. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nash_embedding_theorems